# For each order without invoice

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

i solve this task with 2 native query but want to solve this with one native query maybe will you show me the way if possible.

it's my first query:

```
select o.id as id,o.date as date,o.customer_id_id as customerId
from orders o left outer join
     invoice i
     on o.id = i.order_id_id
where i.order_id_id is null 
intersect 
select o.id as id,o.date as date,o.customer_id_id as customerId
from detail d join
     orders o
     on o.id = d.order_id_id
```

it's my second query and i use from first query o.id it's mean ?1=o.id:

```
select sum(d.quantity*p.price)
from product p join
     detail d
     on p.id=d.product_id_id
where d.order_id_id=?1
```

it is grafic of project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3y87.png)

text of task:For each order without invoice, list its ID, the date it was placed and the total price of the
products in its detail, taking into account the quantity of each ordered product and its unit
price. Orders without detail must not be included in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is an aggregation query after joining three tables (`orders`, `detail`, `product`).  You can use `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE` to filter out the orders with no invoices:

```
select o.id, o.date, o.customer_id_id as customer_id, 
       sum(d.quantity*p.price)
from orders o join
     detail d
     on o.id = d.order_id_id join
     product p 
     on p.id = d.product_id_id
where not exists (select 1
                  from invoices i
                  where o.id = i.order_id_id
                 )
group by o.id, o.date, o.customer_id_id;
```

Comment: thanks bro it was a very nice solution